# Can a RF 433.92 Mhz transceiver communicate to a RF 433.42 Mhz Receiver?

Tags: arduino, rf, transmitter, remote-control, 433mhz

I am working on automating my Somfy Blinds. The idea is to avoid using the remote control which works on 433.42 Mhz and use a simple RF transmitter and an Arduino.
The thing is that I can not find any transceiver at such frequency. I only can get RF 433.92 Mhz transceiver like [RFM69 @ 433 MHz](https://www.adafruit.com/products/3230) among others that only mention 433 Mhz without precision. 
I read from other projects that this will work just fine for short distances, let's say 5-10m.
So before buying a module that won't work I just wanted to drop the question here for the expert

Comment: Do some more research on precisely what your blinds need regards the tuning of the receiver. 433.92 MHz is dead centre of the ISM band but that doesn't mean a particular transmitter uses any particular frequency or remains stable in that band. Do some more research on your blinds i.e. speak with the supplier.

Comment: I can't ask the supplier. This is a hack to avoid having multiple remote controls around the house. So ultimately I will control everything from my smart-phone.

Comment: Then reserve one remote control for hacking into and use relay contacts for activating the switches driven from an independent RF system (plenty on the market such as for garage door openers etc..)

Comment: The spare remote control cost 36 to 56€, while the transmitter 2.0 to 11€. But that is not the point of my question. Anyway going for the spare control remote solution is no fun. Because I could modify directly the motor's receiver

Comment: Then buy some and try it if you want fun. It just might work!

Comment: Not a lot more detail, but this may help https://github.com/Nickduino/Somfy_Remote
and
https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/somfy/

Comment: That is where I read that the signal can be received a short distance even though it is not the same frequency. But I wanted to double check with you guys, electrical engineers.

Comment: @Andyaka Dead center of what ISM band? In Europe, the 433 band and 434 band have different requirements: 433 doesn't allow nearly as much output power unless you duty cycle at 10%. While the 434.040 - 434.900 band allows up to 10mW ERP. (National exceptions do exist in Germany, France, Sweden, Netherlands etc.) The linked radio says "+13 to +20 dBm up to 100 mW Power Output Capability (power output selectable in software)" but doesn't mention duty cycle, so I doubt this module could be used at all, unless there is some way to lower output power to legal levels.

Comment: @Lundin OFCOM in the UK use that term: "433.05-434.79 MHz (centre frequency 433.92 MHz)" taken from here: http://static.ofcom.org.uk/static/spectrum/fat.html and I wasn't trying to make a critical distinction at all.

Comment: @Andyaka I think the 433.92 is some historic frequency from the days when every country had their own laws for the 433 band, in which case it would indeed be the very center of that band in many countries. But since 2003, the EU has tried to harmonize the use of the band (2006/771/EC) and basically say that the whole of 433.050 to 434.900 is 10mW ERP 10% duty cycle. Since the duty cycle requirement doesn't make much sense in many applications, most countries only put requirement that on the 433.050 - 434.040 part of the band.

Comment: Other countries like those mentioned skip the duty cycle requirement entirely. Some allow slightly higher output like 25mW ERP or 15mW ERP. But EU-wide, the only safe bet nowadays is 10mW ERP on 434.040 to 434.900. At any rate, it is probably not a good idea to regard the whole of 433.050 - 434.900 as a single band nowadays.

Comment: I ran across this link while searching for a solution to control my blinds without
using a remote. https://pushstack.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/reversing-somfy-rts/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/161572)

Comment: I understand that links can disappear in time.  However this one contains too much info, including code, as well as additional links to summarize.  I would suggest anyone who might be interested in this topic to make their own copies in case it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 500 KHz offset frequency would be substantially weakened by the filter of a decent OOK receiver at these frequencies, however, some lower cost appliances may use fairly wide receivers.

But that is really beside the point here, as the RFM69 is not a fixed frequency radio, rather it is configurable to a range of frequencies and modulation types, including the ~433.4 MHz or therabouts OOK used by a Somfy shade.  So the premise of the question comes only from misunderstanding, and is moot.

Still, your task is not that simple either, as Somfy shades use a rolling code scheme.  You will not be able to control one without transmitting a code which changes at each transmission in accordance with that scheme, and pairing your code sequence to the shade receiver.

Comment: According to the documentation https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/RFM69HCW-V1.1.pdf p.16, write `0x6C7AE1` across addresses `0x07` to `0x09` will give `433,919983 MHz`

Answer (score 2):

Somfy use 443,42Mhz for carrier and RTS rolling code. Independantly of rolling code, 443 generic transmitter and receiver (as low cost chinese modules) use 443,92Mhz Frequency. Using this frequency on receiver as Somfy motor tuned on 443,42 works but only at short distance  (around 5m depended of course of walls in sight of views)
About RTS and rolling code you can read lot of info on https://www.domoticz.com/forum/

Answer (score 2):

The README of the following github project contains some valuable information regarding this topic: https://github.com/Nickduino/Pi-Somfy 
In summary: Some cheap 433MHz transmitter modules are availabe. However those often use the frequency 433.92 MHz and require soldering skills to replace a 3-Pin 433.92 MHz chip with a 433.42 MHz chip using the same pin out. 
I was yet unable to find a source which sells 433.42 MHz transmitter modules ready to use which don't require such a soldering patchwork.

Answer (score 1):

Somfy in the US have a product called URTSI II which can be intefaced to using RS-232, RS-485 or IR so that might work for you. Not sure where you are located but I believe Somfy US use 433.42 and here in Australia and possibly Europe use 433.92.